# Запрос возвращает null

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть запрос:

```
select  @a=sum(количество )  from Заявка where Статус='В пути' AND Заявка.Наименование_детали=@с  group by Наименование_детали
```

Он возвращает null, можно ли сделать что бы он возвращал нуль?
Из за этого не работает обновление

```
update Ведомость_материалов set Чистая_потребность=@b-Колличество_на_складе-@a where Ведомость_материалов.Материал=@q
```

т.к. чиcло-null=null

Comment: `...=coalesce(sum(количество), 0)...`

Comment: ... или `... ISNULL(SUM(количество), 0)`... 
Кстати, для чего у Вас в исходном запросе `group by`?

Answer (score 1):

ну или через CASE

> ...= case when sum(количество ) is null then 0 else sum(количество ) end